# Hitting [Authorize] always redirects to /account/login in IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4, openid-connect

If I hit an endpoint that has the `[Authorize]` attribute, I get redirected to `/Account/Login?returnUrl=XXX`.

Is there a way to change this behavior? I've already changed `LoginUrl` in `IdentityServerOptions.UserInteraction` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

We can change this by setting `LoginPath` in `CookieAuthenticationOptions`, although the accepted parameter is a `PathString`, meaning if you'd like to redirect the user to another website, you'd have to use one of the events in the options, more specifically - `CookieAuthenticationOptions.Events.RedirectToAccessDenied`.